# How do I update a specific span text in a repetitive list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to update the text of `class="count"` in the span when the "Helpful" `span  class="upvote"` is clicked. I use ajax to update the value in the database then I use the result to display in the count span.

However with my code below it updates all of them.

I have the below html

```
<div class="question">  
    <span class="upvote" data-id="1" data-cat="question"> Helpful <span class="count">2</span></span>   
</div>

<div class="answers">   
    <span class="upvote" data-id="3" data-cat="answer"> Helpful <span class="count">15</span></span>
    <span class="upvote" data-id="4" data-cat="answer"> Helpful <span class="count">66</span></span>
    <span class="upvote" data-id="6" data-cat="answer"> Helpful <span class="count">0</span></span> 
</div>
```

Here's my jquery

```
$('.upvote').click(function(event) {                
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/ask/upvote',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            cat_id: $(this).data('id'),
            category: $(this).data('cat'),
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {               
            $(".upvote span").text(json);
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the reference of the `upvote` which was clicked

```
$('.upvote').click(function(event) {                
    let $clicked = $(this);  //reference saved
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/ask/upvote',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            cat_id: $(this).data('id'),
            category: $(this).data('cat'),
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {               
            $clicked.find( ".count" ).text(json); //observe changes in this line
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Per his code I think he only want update the number span, so you could use $(this).children("count")